# Media device design patent and other types of products

Tags: design-patent, apple, freedom-to-operate, usd497618

If design patent is granted for a media device, will it also cover other devices which are not “media devices”?

For instance, [US D497,618 S1](https://www.google.com/patents/USD497618) is a design patent for an iPod.

If someone makes a toy, case, or even just a statuette that looks like the above design but is not a media device, will it infringe?

Answer (score 2):

It the claim states media device - no. But in the case of the iPod, there are probably other rights protecting aspects of the design (trademarks, copyrights).